# ASP.NET, IIS and SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7

My scenario is: I have 3 separate machines for domain controller (Windows 2008), SQL Server 2008 and IIS (Windows 7).

I am maintaining table log using a SQL Server trigger (Delete, Update, Insert),
by setting `suser_name()` as default value e.g:

- Table1: TrNo Bigint, TrDate Datetime, CDate as datetime
- Table1_Log: TrNo Bigint, TrDate Datetime, CDate as datetime, AuditUser Varchar(100) default suser_name()

Whenever user updates any record, it maintain its log tables. My problem is that  it always show same ComputerName in log table that configured is IIS.

What I did in IIS :

```
Application - 
               Anonymous Authentication  - Disabled
               ASP.Net Impersonation     - Disabled
               Basic Authentication      - Disabled
               Form Authentication       - Disabled    
               Windows Authentication    - Enabled
Application Pools - 
               Default Application Pool
                              Identity - Network Services

--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now when I run the application it show a windows dialog box where user entered his `Domain\UserName`  and when I edit any record, it save my computer name to `AuditUser` column (i-e:  `suser_name()`).

I want to save actual username that I entered in Windows dialog box. `suser_name()`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your application is running as the identity specified in your IIS application pool.  In order for it to connect to SQL Server as the individual identities, you will need to enable impersonation.

This involves enabling impersonation in your web.config

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Then in your code you use a `WindowsImpersonationContext` to wrap those parts of code where you would like to impersonate that user (e.g.  In your case, during your database calls).

```
var identity = User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;

using (var context = identity.Impersonate())
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Keep in mind that means all of these users will need access rights in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply 
'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'
on Connection.open()